# Is it possible to catch all exceptions for requests? (and generally, for a module)

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, python-requests

I have some code which will make a `requests.get()` call, which may fail in various ways. I want to catch `requests` exceptions, but do not care about why the call failed.

I would like to avoid code like

```
try:
    r = requests.get(url)
except:
    pass
```

because it will possible catch exceptions which are not `requests` related (in the case above this would hardly be the case but if there was some more code it would be possible).

`requests` exceptions are [documented](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/_modules/requests/exceptions/) but I would prefer not to list all of them. **Is there a way to catch them all, some kind of wildcard on `requests` exceptions?** (and more generally - for exceptions provided by a module)

I could also go for something like

```
try:
    r = requests.get(url)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

but I would like to avoid analyzing `e` to filter out `requests` exceptions.

Note: this is not a duplicate of a [question on handling all but one exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16123529/handling-all-but-one-exception) - I am targeting a whole class of related exceptions (and allow for a crash if something else raises an exception, which in my case would be a bug)

Comment: For `requests` you can always use `RequestsException` from which all inherit from what I can see. You can't work with exceptions that just might be defined in the same module (you could catch em all and filter out things in the `except` clause but that might get messy).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Handling all but one exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16123529/handling-all-but-one-exception)

Comment: @Marat: this is not a duplicate - I want to catch a whole class of related exceptions, not "catch everything except one" (where I would just chain two `except` instances)

Comment: @JimFasarakisHilliard: thank you, your comments covers both the `request` case (my immediate problem) and the general case (= it cannot be done, except filtering as I mentioned in my question). Would you mind turning this into an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good library designers will *usually* create a base exception(s) for their library from which other exceptions will derive.

For `requests` this is `RequestException` according to the [documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/_modules/requests/exceptions/) you linked; using it in the `except` clause will catch anything that derives from it.

```
try:
    # code involving requests 
    # that might err
except RequestException:
    # ignore, handle..
```

As stated in the comment and in the question, discriminating based on the module they are defined in cannot be done *automatically* (i.e in the `except` clause expression; you'd have to add that logic yourself in the body of the `except` clause.