# How to ignore one particular exception in Python?

Tags: python, exception

I have a `try` block case in my code and I want to ignore one particular exception and all the rest should be raised.

For example:

```
try:
 blah
except <exception> as e:
 raise Exception(e)
```

In this kind of case, I want all the exceptions to be raised except for one case, say if the exception is "query not found" I have to ignore it.

How do I ignore that single exception?

I can use multiple except blocks but how to define a exception?

Comment: you can add multiple except clause

Comment: It's sort of the reverse of [Handling all but one exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16123529/handling-all-but-one-exception). Catch that specific exception and re-`raise` all the others.

Comment: Can you clarify what you are struggling with? You are already showing the code for handling (and thus ignoring) a specific exception. What do you mean by "I want all the exceptions to be raised"? When handling exceptions, they have *already* been raised – simply not handling them means they will proceed. Do you want to re-raise them as a different exception?

Comment: "I can use multiple except blocks but how to define the exception?" Please clarify *what* exception you want to ignore. What defines "the exception" in logical terms? For example, just ``KeyError`` but not ``LookupError``? A specific ``KeyError`` *value*, i.e. with specific ``e.args``? A specific ``KeyError`` *instance*, i.e. identified by identity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give something like this:

```
try:
  print(x)
except NameError:
  print("Variable x is not defined")
except:
  print("Something else went wrong")
```

In this case, you want to catch NameError and specify a message. For all others, you want to specify another message.

Let's say you want to ignore NameError, then you can just give `continue` or `pass`.

Alternatively, you can also raise an exception.

Example will be:

```
x = -1

if x < 0:
  raise Exception("Sorry, no numbers below zero")
```

So you can use a combination of all this to get you what you want.

If you want more details on exception, see the below links:

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html

https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_try_except.asp

https://realpython.com/python-exceptions/

And on stack overflow (as Gino highlighted), see
[Handling all but one exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16123529/handling-all-but-one-exception)

Comment: For all others, I think OP wants to re-raise, so maybe a bare `raise` instead.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to @Joe Ferndz's answer, in case you don't want the exception to be raised but still want the block to exit, you can use suppress from the contextlib module:

```
from contextlib import suppress

with suppress(ValueError):
    print('hello world')
    raise ValueError
    print('this will not be printed')
```

In this case, the block still exits on raise ValueError, but an exception is not raised.